# How make kendoUI Drag-and-drop work correct?

Tags: jquery, sorting, drag-and-drop, kendo-ui

I'm using kendoUI drag-and-drop control to make sort to my list. I find this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rusev/nmB69/ and there everything works correct, but when I implement this in my website It isn't work.

I use `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` and `kendo.all.min.js` on my page.

If you look to fiddle you can see some `console.log`. Values which I log in this are different for fiddle and my application for example:

**in fiddle i get in console:**

```
1
u.extend.f
[<td>3</td>]
u.extend.f
```

**in the same situation in my application I get:**

```
undefined
undefined
[<td>Text 1</td>]
undefined
```

And element which is created in hint parameter is displaying after I drop it.

I'm new in Kendo UI so I have no idea how fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you forgot the link to the fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and had the same problem as you. Then I noticed that the jsfiddle example is using Kendo UI v2011.3.1129 and I was using Kendo UI Beta v2012.2.621. There were [breaking changes](http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/changes-and-backward-compatibility.aspx) between these versions.

The solution would be to either use the same version as the jsfiddle example or to change your code. I changed my code in two places when getting the datasouce. The Grid widget is now using the uid field of the Model instead of the id, which represents its unique id. Also, in order to retrieve Model instance by its uid, DataSource's getByUid method should be used.

jsfiddle example:

```
var target = dataSource.get($(e.draggable.currentTarget).data("id"))
```

changed code

```
var target = dataSource.getByUid($(e.draggable.currentTarget).data("uid"))
```

This has to be done for both the target and destination.

```
    grid.table/*.find("tbody > tr")*/.kendoDropTarget({
      group: "gridGroup",
      drop: function (e) {
        var target = dataSource.getByUid($(e.draggable.currentTarget).data("uid")),
              dest = $(e.target);

        if (dest.is("th")) {
          return;
        }
        dest = dataSource.getByUid(dest.parent().data("uid"));

        //not on same item
        if (target.get("id") !== dest.get("id")) {
          //reorder the items
          var tmp = target.get("position");
          target.set("position", dest.get("position"));
          dest.set("position", tmp);

          dataSource.sort({ field: "position", dir: "asc" });
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed approach to my problem :)

Comment: I am also getting problem. The above code works fine in firefox but dest is always undefined in chrome. Any hack for this?